# Integration factor for $x' + \lambda x = 0 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For following ode

$\frac{dx}{dt} + \lambda x(t) = 0 $

we have integration factor as

$e^{\int\lambda x}$

so resolving it gets us

$e^{\lambda t}$

is this correct?

Comment: It's $\mu (t)=\exp\int \lambda dt=e^{\lambda t}$

Comment: But we are working in time domain 't' .. also why x is replaced with dx in the term in the middle ?

Comment: Then the integral must have no x in it. This is not correct $e^{\int\lambda x}$ but your final answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check that: 
$$(e^{\lambda t}\times x(t) )' = (\lambda e^{\lambda t}x(t)) + (e^{\lambda t}x'(t))$$
so, $$= e^{\lambda t}\left( x'(t)+\lambda x(t) \right)$$

as you can see, the factor you need is $e^{\lambda t}$.